# A short and mathemtical way to check that only one variable is not 0

Tags: java, variables, vector

I have a given method `Direction calculateDirection(Vector3 from, Vector3 to)`
where *Vector3 contains X, Y, Z*.

The purpose of the method is to calculate a straight line direction, it cannot be diagonal, it can only be `X_LEFT` or `X_RIGHT`, or `Z_LEFT`, or `Z_RIGHT` or `TOP` or `DOWN`.

So I started getting the offsets:

```
Direction calculateDirection(Vector3 from, Vector3 to) {
    int x = from.getX() - to.getX();
    int y = from.getY() - to.getY();
    int z = from.getZ() - to.getZ();
}
```

So to know the direction, one of these variables should not be 0, and if there are more than one variable that is not 0, I would need to return `null` or throw an `exception`.

To do this, I would need to perform a few `if`, `elseif` but I don't feel comfortable with this, I feel like there can be a more simple mathematical solution.

For example, if only `x` is not `0` then I can check if its negative, if yes then its `X_LEFT`.

**I would like to add that X, Y, Z can either be -1, 0 or 1.**

Comment: Assuming your ultimate goal is readable clean code, why don't you implement the `if-elseif` computation in methods with readable names and use them inside `calculateDirection`?

Comment: @C-Otto That's an idea I thought of using as a plan-b if I would not be able to find some kind of a mathematical way, since my values can either be -1 or 0 or 1, I have a feeling I am missing something that may shorten the code.

Comment: Just use some if as already said by @C-Otto, that's the simple way.

Comment: Can you provide a correct solution with if statements? I'm not sure I understand what you expect the output to be in all cases. Also, a more precise description input would be very helpful. For instance, are we dealing with doubles or ints? What's the range of acceptable values?

Comment: When you say **X,Y, Z** are you talking about `x, y ,z` of a `Vector3` or the `int` variables that you have calculated (offsets)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you don't just want to verify that only one is not zero, but you actually need to determine a `Direction` value.

Since the value of `x` can only be `-1`, `0`, or `1`, if you add `1` you get that `x` can be `0`, `1`, or `2`, which will fit in 2 bits. If you then do the same for `y` and `z` and shift their bits, you can then combine all 3 into a single `int` value.

Technically, you only need to shift 2 to prevent bit overlap, but for clarity we'll shift `y` by 4 and `z` by 8, so they'll each be in a separate [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble).

```
switch ((x + 1) | ((y + 1) << 4) | ((z + 1) << 8)) {
    case 0x110: return Direction.X_LEFT;  // x == -1, y ==  0, z ==  0
    case 0x112: return Direction.X_RIGHT; // x ==  1, y ==  0, z ==  0
    case 0x101: return Direction.DOWN;    // x ==  0, y == -1, z ==  0
    case 0x121: return Direction.TOP;     // x ==  0, y ==  1, z ==  0
    case 0x011: return Direction.Z_LEFT;  // x ==  0, y ==  0, z == -1
    case 0x211: return Direction.Z_RIGHT; // x ==  0, y ==  0, z ==  1
    default:    return null;              // other invalid combination
}
```

Does this *bit manipulation* cover your desire for a "simple mathematical solution"?

Comment: I generally avoid bit manipulation and switch statements whenever possible.  But I think this is a good use for them.  Every alternative I can think of is way too wordy and just "feels bad".  +1 for finding a great place to use techniques that can easily be abused.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java 8's `stream` to count zero values, e.g.:

```
long zeroValueCount = Stream.of(x, y, z)
                        .filter(e -> e != 0)
                        .count();
```

If `zeroValueCount` is not 1, you can return `null` or throw an `Exception`. This would validate the values. However, as far as returning values is concerned, you need to use `switch` or lookup a `Map` structure.

Answer (score 1):

if you want a simple yet readable way maybe try this:

```
if (Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y) + Math.abs(z) < 2)
  // at least 2 values are 0
```

the use of `abs` is necessary because of the negative values obviously.

if you need to do more checks you can also save the addition and decide your return value on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y) + Math.abs(z) == 1)
```

followed by if else statements to find out which one has a value

Answer (score 0):

I would use this approach:

```
Direction calculateDirection(Vector3 from, Vector3 to) {
    int x = from.getX() - to.getX();
    int y = from.getY() - to.getY();
    int z = from.getZ() - to.getZ();

    int sum = Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y) + Math.abs(z);
    if (sum != 1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Wrong input.");
    }

    return x == 0
            ? (y == 0 ? (z == -1 ? Direction.Z_LEFT : Direction.Z_RIGHT)
                    : (y == -1 ? Direction.DOWN : Direction.TOP))
            : (x == -1 ? Direction.X_LEFT : Direction.X_RIGHT);
}
```